# Crystal Report: Load Report failed

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am having some problem with my report using Crystal Report.

Can anyone tell me what is the cause of this error? and how to fix it.

The system has encountered while executing your request ...

`Source ::CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Message ::Load report failed`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: may you catch the exception and get more details? here are some possible causes that i met before: (1) the path of the rpt file is incorrect; (2) the rpt file is corrupted

Comment: You need to provide some more details. You can have a look at this for a start though: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/76819/Crystal-Reports-Fix-for-Load-report-failed-error